# Install TFTP-Server without Internet

Tags: centos, tftp

Due to some company policy, I cannot connect my Centos linux computer to the internet. 
However, I would like to set up a TFTP-Server, and I saw a tutorial that does this here. 
http://n40lab.wordpress.com/2014/01/29/centos-6-5-installing-a-tftpd-server-for-uploading-configuration-files/
Once I run yum install it goes and searches for the dependancy files on the internet.

My question is : Is there any way for me to install TFTP-Server without connecting to the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a note of the packages that `yum` wanted to download.  Use an Internet connected machine to download those packages.  Place them on an CD/DVD/USB-stick and import them into your CentOS machine.

`cd` to the directory where you've imported them and run:

```
yum install <package-1> <package-2>
```

I did a quick test on my CentOS 7 machine and the packages consisted of `xinted` and `tftp-server` therefore it should be easy enough.

Another option would be to download the full ISOs of CentOS and burn to DVD.  Then configure the CentOS machine to use that as a repo. Bear in mind that the packages will be relatively dated (as I write, they are 9 months old).

Finally, you could `rsync` a repository's `Packages` and `repodata` directories onto a large USB-stick or a USB HDD, then mount this on your CentOS system. Create a `.repo` file that points to this mount and install `tftp-server`.  This will have the advantage that the package will be the latest available.  You could even `yum update` the whole server.

Comment: Thanks. I took the 2nd option. All I had to do was to change the repository to point to the Centos dvd. Viola! I could install tftp-server!